# The point of signed measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am learning the signed measure these days. And I don't really get the point of it. I often see such sentences as " in order to represent all the functions... we need to use the signed measure."

$$g = \int f d\mu$$
Why can't we just flip the sign of part of the function so that we don't need the signed measure?

What I don't understand is we can flip the sign of the function to substitute the negative part of the measure. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the sentence you cite is referring to the fact that the space of signed measures (equipped with the total variation norm) is a Banach space and its dual is $C_0$ (the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity). This is the statement of the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_continuous_dual_of_C0(X)).

BTW: One could argue that (finite) signed measures are more naturally than ordinary measures, since they are simply a special case of general vector measures.

Comment: Does it mean there exist some functions we have to use the signed measure to represent?

Comment: It precisely means that any continuous linear functional on $C_0(X)$ ($X$ being a locally compact Hausdorff space) is of the form $f\mapsto\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$ for some signed measure on $\mathcal B(X)$ admitting some regularity properties (be warned that the term "Borel measure" is not used in a consistent way in the literature).